# Want to be fair to potential employer

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I’ve been offered a job (“JOB A”) while waiting to hear on another job (“JOB B”).  JOB A is a sure thing and they are just waiting to hear back from me as to whether or not I’ll accept.  JOB B felt like a sure thing at one time but they have pushed the start date back again and again for two months now and I’m starting to wonder if it will ever happen. JOB A is a permanent job but only pays about ½ as much as JOB B which is an 8 week contract-to-hire job.  Is it alright to accept JOB A knowing that if JOB B comes along I will have to quit at a moments notice?  I really like the people at JOB A and they are very excited about the possibility of having me work for them.  I just don’t feel right accepting JOB A unless I totally forget about JOB B.  Also, I’ve been out of work for about 4 months and really need to get some money coming in.  What to do?  What to do?

Comment: Your feelings on this are well founded. It would be completely unethical to take Job A if you're willing to cast it aside as soon as you hear back from B. Understandable that the prospect of a much higher rate tempting, having said that. I think you already have one solid answer, hopefully you'll get more.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, job B has nothing for it except the higher pay and doesn't even guarantee conversion to full-time. They could bait-and-switch you to lower salary once FT. (Been there). Especially given the 4 months off.

Just accept A already. Or go back to A, tell them you are excited by the opportunity, but mention that a competing offer, while not as interesting, if offering significantly more. Raising their offer slightly would cast away any lingering doubt you have. See what you can get. Stay polite and positive, simply mention that a slight increase in the offer would seal the deal.